# Number of distinct perfect matchings in a cycle

Tags: graph-theory, operations-research

What is the number of distinct perfect matchings in a cycle of length $n$ (where $n\ge3$) ?

Comment: I've tried to draw some instances but haven't got any idea about a pattern. Can you drop a hint?

Comment: The answer is unfortunately too short to call a hint. Two matchings if n is even, none otherwise (because only an even-order graph can have a perfect matching).

Comment: that's true. I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Odd number of vertices won't make up for perfect matching. And regarding even number of vertices,for a cycle graph, number of perfect matchings is 2.
For a square (cycle graph of 4 vertices) , let's say a is adjacent to b and c. c is adjacent to a and d. d is adjacent to c and b. Now the perfect matching sets are { (a,b) (c,d) } or { (a,c) (b,d) } So we see there are 2 perfect matchings for a cycle graph (C2n). You can try for any cycle length (NOT odd) and find its perfect matching to be 2.